# Core data FIFO? (first in first out)

Tags: ios, core-data

Im sitting with this issue bugging me. I have core data working fine, but when it fetches, in my case, the users, they come back in different orders. Normally would use the standard unique identifier, but core data doesn't have this. So....
Do I manually create an ID entity_property and assign it incrementally, or is the "object id" being made in incremental order; incremented maybe by 1, or just random IDs? hence making me able to use object id.

My goal is to get my fetched array in the same order the users was inserted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need your own technique for generating the unique ID. Run that code in your `NSManagedObject` subclass's `-awakeFromInsert`, which is called once, when the object is inserted into the datastore. You can add a timestamp, or the value of an incrementing counter.

There's no built-in support for an autoincrement ID. You'll need a class variable, and increment that yourself in `-awakeFromInsert`. You'll also have to persist that value across launches, either as its own Entity or within the persistent store's metadata.

You might benefit from using an ordered relationship, if those users have a one-to-many relationship with some other entity.

The `NSManagedObjectID` is unique within the store, but will change when the `NSManagedObjectContext` is saved (and the NSMOID goes from temporary to permanent). No promises are made about its sequence or pattern of construction. And it can change during a managed object model migration. So don't depend on it for anything you need to control.

Answer (score 0):

core data does not return ORDERED data. so, if your data is "string" or "date" type then you can simply sort your data by ascending/descending after fetching from code-data.

Comment: you can see http://www.iosrocketsurgery.com/2013/12/ios-core-data-nsfetchrequest-sort.html#.VfxZ-nvq5PM

Comment: yes well, problem is that is has to be sorted the way it came in, not by any properties i have. hence my interest in object id/core data auto generated unique identifier of some sort

Comment: so, you need to use "auto increment" id